# Accessing Database in assets and calling it from MainActivity

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I want to access database in assets folder. I made a DataBaseHelper class in my project and copied the code below. Now i want to know how to call this class in my MainActivity. I called it like

DataBaseHandler db=new DataBaseHandler(this);

But got an error

Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

So can someone help with how to call this in my project and use the database created.

```
 public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
 private Context mycontext;

//private String DB_PATH = mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "(datbasename).sqlite";//the extension may be .sqlite or .db
public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
/*private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                    + mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                    + "/databases/";*/

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException {
    super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
    this.mycontext=context;
    boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
    if (dbexist) {
        //System.out.println("Database exists");
        opendatabase(); 
    } else {
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
        createdatabase();
    }
}

public void createdatabase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
    if(dbexist) {
        //System.out.println(" Database exists.");
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copydatabase();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}   

private boolean checkdatabase() {
    //SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
    boolean checkdb = false;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        //checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        checkdb = dbfile.exists();
    } catch(SQLiteException e) {
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
    }
    return checkdb;
}

private void copydatabase() throws IOException {
    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/(packagename)/databases   /(datbasename).sqlite");

    // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0) {
        myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myoutput.flush();
    myoutput.close();
    myinput.close();
}

public void opendatabase() throws SQLException {
    //Open the database
    String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public synchronized void close() {
    if(myDataBase != null) {
        myDataBase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you only use existing database, no need to extends from SQLiteOpenHelper.

Your DatabaseHandler should be like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DataBaseHelper {
    private Context mycontext;

    private String DB_PATH = mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "your_db_name.sqlite";//the extension may be .sqlite or .db
    public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
/*private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                    + mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                    + "/databases/";*/

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException {
        this.mycontext = context;
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if (!dbexist) {
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
            copydatabase();
        }
        opendatabase();
    }

    private boolean checkdatabase() {
        //SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
        boolean checkdb = false;
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        //checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        checkdb = dbfile.exists();
        return checkdb;
    }

    private void copydatabase() throws IOException {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);

        // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myinput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myoutput.flush();
        myoutput.close();
        myinput.close();
    }

    public void opendatabase() throws SQLException {
        //Open the database
        String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null) {
            myDataBase.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that the code above is not safe, just use for studying only.

Comment: Because you can instantiate DataBaseHelper as much as you want, so there will be more than one connection to database at a time. I think it's not safe, for example when working with multi thread.
I usually apply singleton pattern to things like this.